# Android Firebase exceptions to Google Analytics

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

1. How to send exceptions from Firebase to Google Analytics through
   Google Tag Manager
   I mean, is it possible to do it the same way of sending events?
2. Is it possible to send the Exception formatted?